# C++ "Space ship"

Tags: c++

Hello stack overflow users! I have a question about my program, and a problem I am encountering. I have practically finished the program, but I can't seem to have a separate void function for my dimensions (width and length of rocket). I currently have them inside my void function that creates my rocket, void draw box, but I cant seem to figure out how to have a separate void function for my dimensions. Any tips or things I am doing wrong to fix this? Any help is appreciated, thanks once again!

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void dimensions (int, int);
void drawBox (int , int , int);

int main ()
{
    int numXs, numSpaces, numRows, width, height;

    //dimensions (width, height);
    drawBox (numXs, numSpaces, numRows);

    return 0;
}

void dimensions (int width, int height)
{
    cout << "Enter width: ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Enter height: ";
    cin >> height;
    cout << endl;
}

void drawBox (int numXs, int numSpaces, int numRows)

{
    int count, rowCount, spaceCount, width, height;

    cout << "Enter width: ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Enter height: ";
    cin >> height;
    cout << endl;

    for (count = 0; count < width; count++)
            {    
                cout << "X";
            }
            cout << endl;

        for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < height; rowCount++)
            {    
                cout << "X";

                if ( width % 2 == 0)
                {
                    for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < width - 2; spaceCount++)
                    {    
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                    cout << "X" << endl;
                }

                else
                {
                    for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < width - 2; spaceCount++)
                    {    
                        cout << "X";
                    }
                    cout << "X" << endl;
                }
            }
            cout << "X";

        for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < numSpaces; spaceCount++)
            {    
                cout << " ";
            }

        for (count = 0; count < width - 1; count++)
            {    
                cout << "X";
            }
            cout << endl;       


    //second box is being created below

for (count = 0; count < width; count++)
        {    
            cout << "X";
        }
        cout << endl;

    for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < height; rowCount++)
        {    
            cout << "X";

            if ( width % 2 == 0)
            {
                for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < width - 2; spaceCount++)
                {    
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << "X" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < width - 2; spaceCount++)
                {    
                    cout << "X";
                }
                cout << "X" << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << "X";

    for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < numSpaces; spaceCount++)
        {    
            cout << " ";
        }

    for (count = 0; count < width - 1; count++)
        {    
            cout << "X";
        }
        cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Who else came here for a question about the spaceship operator?

Comment: BTW, you are passing variables *by copy* to the `dimensions` function.  They have no correlation to the variables in `main`.  If you want to modify the parameters to a function, pass them by reference.

Comment: @user4581301, I did as well, lol. But I eventually figured everything out BUT, the void function for dimensions. Cant see to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: @EduardoMunozAlvarez You might not beware of it, so here a short explanation: There is a feature in the very new C++20, the [three-way comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison). It is also called the "*spaceship operator*" because of how it looks. But that has nothing to do with drawing rockets ;D

Comment: @walnut you are super right, I was not aware of that lol. Thanks for informing me on that lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your variables by reference:

```
void dimensions(int& height, int& width)
{
    height = 5;
    width = -6; // Because int is signed, this is possible.
}

int main()
{
    int tall = -42;
    int length = 22;
    dimensions(tall, length);
    std::cout << "tall: " << tall << "\n";
    std::cout << "length: " << length << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making height and width global variables, so that you can use them in both functions?

Comment: Many coding guidelines say "global variables are evil".

Comment: Yes, and they need to be used carefully.

Comment: Pass by reference solves this far more elegantly than global variables.

Comment: @Nikola Yes I have, but unfortunately, I cant use global variables, as I have certain guide lines I have to meet. And one of the guidelines was not to use global variables, as it would make it way easier.

Comment: Then just do what @ThomasMatthews said. It will solve your problem.